# Can I get back to the main menu without exiting completely?

Tags: realm-of-the-mad-god

I seem to be unable to get back to the main menu/title screen without completely exiting the game and restarting it. This is a bit annoying, as it seems to be the only place that you can change which character you're playing or what server you're on.

Is there any shortcut or menu option to go back to the main title screen that I'm missing somewhere? Or am I forced to completely close the game and restart in order to get there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no shortcut to do so. However, you can use a "portal" to get there.

In the Nexus, there's a **gray warrior statue**, which can be used to change characters.

[image]

Stand in front of it, then click the "Change" button in the lower right corner. You'll disconnect from the current server and go back to the character selection screen. From there, you can click "main" to go back to the main menu.

Comment: Thank you! The server I'm on was so full that that guy was completely covered, so I couldn't see him.

Comment: @FAE Yeah, it's a bit obscure and easily mistaken for a player, especially when there's dozens of players milling around. Took me about a week to notice him.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is Press the letter o which sends you into the setting screen, then in the bottom left you will see "Back to Main Menu " There you go!